# Why is the DVD-drive listed as part of the disk 0 in diskpart?

Tags: windows, windows-10, diskpart

When listing the contents of disk 0 via

```
select disk 0
list volume
```

there are entries such as my DVD-drive and mass-storage listed. How comes?

They're in my way to convert the disk to GPT. Help me to get them out of my way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

[image]

In which case please notice the difference between `LIST PARTITION` and `LIST VOLUME`. The first explicitly mentions **on the selected disk**. The second does not use such a filter and will list all mounted volumes.

> They're in my way to convert the disk to GPT.

How are they in your way? What is the actual problem when you try to convert from MBR to GPT? What are the commands you are using andn what is the actuyal output?

(e.g. `diskpart` `select disk 1` `convert gpt`).

Comment: Diskpart tells me that it cannot convert the MBR to GPT due to DVDs etc. being attached even after your suggestion. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the precise error? And are the DVD being mounted from a DVDROM or via software loopback?

Comment: The DVD and flash card not being mounted at all diskpart lists them as part of the disk and logically complains that they cannot be converted along the SSD partition table.

Comment: "and logically complains that they cannot be converted along the SSD partition table"... What is the precise error message?

Comment: It has nothing to do with volumes! Forget about "list volume" and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
list disk
select disk="X"
convert gpt
```

Where "X" is the number of desired disk in the list to convert to GPT.

**Note: Volumes and Partitions do not convert to GPT! MBR/GPT are partition table structures that apply to the whole disk!**